# Correlation of number of full nodes to network hash rate

Tags: full-node, monero-network-hashrate

Is there any historical data tracking the number of full nodes over time?

If such data exists is there any where I can find it plotted against the [network hash rate over time](http://monerostats.com/charts/?type=basic)?

I am interested in learning how closely related the number of full nodes and network hash rate are related.

Answer (score 1):

No one can know the number of full nodes at any given time, because not all nodes connect to each other, and there is no way of knowing about nodes that you are not directly connected to. Node information is not obtainable from the blockchain.